# Is in ios something similar to android startActivityForResult?

Tags: ios, ios7

From one UIViewController I am opening another modal segue

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"new" sender:self];
```

, do some things and from modal I call code

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
```

and I am again in first controller. My question is in ios something similar to android `startActivityForResult` to start new modal UIViewController and fetch result or when it is closed to pass through some function inside first/parent controller and check some things?

( I put break points in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` but it didn't pass when it is back from modal => in android there is `onResume` which is called every time activity/uiviewcontroller is going to be visible again, is in ios something similar)

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to use them exactly, but you're probably looking for `unwindSegue`.  Happy googling.  (Or perhaps someone that is more familiar with them can explain `unwindSegue` to you in an answer).